# ArcGIS Javascript Editor - showAttributesOnClick feature

Tags: arcgis-server, javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, editing

I'm using the Editor dijit to add feature to my map. I was looking at [one of the online samples](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/ed_simpletoolbar.html), which mentions a "showAttributesOnClick" setting in the description. When I look at the code in that same sample, that setting isn't used and it's not documented in the API. Does that feature still exist? Has it been replaced with something else?

I'd like to only display the AttributeInspector for a new feature, and hide it for existing ones.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't familiar with that property so I took a look at the minified source and it doesn't look like 'showAttributesOnClick' or an equivalent constructor property exists.

i'll let the development team know they need to correct the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

No such option is available for Editor Widget, and development is aware of the issue. The updated document will be available in the next release.